# getopt immediately exiting loop

Tags: c, getopt

I am trying to get getopt to work with my C program, but I have found that it is not working.
Here is the function that doesn't work

```
char* getFlagArg(int argc, char **argv, char flag) {
 extern char *optarg;
 extern int optind, optopt, opterr;
 char opt;
 char options[3] = {flag,':',0};
 while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, options)) != -1) {
     if(opt == flag)
         return optarg;
 }
 return "";
}
```

When I run this code, it immediately exits the loop (the loop does not run even once).  I can't figure out why this is happening.  I have verified that argc, argv, and options are all what I expect them to be.  Thoughts?  Please and thank you!

Comment: "I have verified that argc, argv, and options are all what I expect them to be." -- and what do you expect them to be?

Comment: From the code, it suggests you're trying to find a specific flag option. What is the command line used to start the program? What is the value of `optind` when you enter this function? What is the value of `optind` when the function exits?

Comment: The command line reads "./a.out -u User FileName"
optind == 3 at the end of the program
By "argc, argv, and options are all what I expect them to be" I mean that argc = 4, argv = ["./a.out", "-u", "User", "FileName"], and flag = 'u'.  So the arguments are all getting passed in correctly.

Comment: What is the value of `optind` before you enter the `while` loop?

Comment: When I call `getFlagArg(4, (char *[]){ "./a.out", "-u", "User", "FileName", 0 }, 'u')`, the `while` is entered exactly once, `opt` is `'u'` in that iteration, the return value of `getFlagArg` points to `"User"` and `optind` is 3 (after the `getopt` call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point I was trying to get at in the question's comments was this:

```
char *arg;

arg = getFlagArg (argc, argv, 'b');
printf ("-b arg = %s\n", arg);
arg = getFlagArg (argc, argv, 'u');
printf ("-u arg = %s\n", arg);
```

If you have called `getFlagArg` or `getopt` already, the second call will possibly fail. Imagine you had an option `-b` that accepted an argument, and the command line was `./a.out -u foo -b quux filename`. Because you searched for `-b` first, `optind` will be 5, and searching for `-u` will fail because `optind` is greater than 1, which is the value `optind` must be to find the `-u` option in the example command line I provided.

You will need to "reset" `getopt` by setting `optind` to 1. Of course, we would need to see the code calling `getFlagArg` if this isn't the problem.

**Edit**

Options without arguments are allowed to be in the same `argv` element. `getopt` can handle this, but if you have two options `-a` and `-c`, `./a.out -cau foo` will work with `getopt`, but you cannot necessarily find `-c` after finding `-a` even by setting `optind` to 1 again. Only after you go through `-u foo` (or any other option requiring an argument) will you be able to reset `optind` and restart parsing.

FreeBSD and likely some other BSD clones provide a nonstandard `optreset` variable to handle this sort of case. Glibc on Linux, however, does not, so beware of this strange "quirk" of `getopt`.

Comment: +1 This is an awful lot like trying to read through a `FILE *` multiple times without resetting the internal pointer back to the beginning of the file. I usually see people grab *all* the command line args in one `while` loop, which avoids this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the problem.  I guess I didn't understand the man page correctly/carefully enough:
_The caller can reset it to 1 to restart scanning of the same argv, or when scanning a new argument vector_

Comment: @Nero144 Glad it helped. One caveat with setting `optind` back to 1 as if it was a "reset button" is explained in my edit, so please read it and note that it only applies to options that _do not_ require arguments. @turbulencetoo provided some useful advice as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should be `int opt` instead of `char c` because it's an integer value that is returned by `getopt()`.  You don't give the version of C that your using; so it's hard to make a test to verify the behavior that you are getting but a suppose that the conversion from `int` to `char` and then back again to `int` make it equal to `-1` in this case.

Of course, you should also change your code with a proper casting for the comparaison with the value of `flag` that follow just below if you change the declaration of `opt`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the cast didn't fix the problem.  I'm using gcc 4.6.3 (does that answer which version of C I'm using?) on an x86_64 Ubuntu.

Comment: What do you mean by using a Cast?  Are you trying to cast the result of getopt to a char?  getopt() return an int, if this int is different from -1 than it can be cast into a char.  The cast that I mentionned was for the comparaison "if(opt == flag)" that you have on the line after and that must be changed if you change the declaration of opt from char to int.  I don't have gcc 4.6.3 or Ubuntu so I cannot test for this but the rest of your code looks OK.  However, it's possible that the transmitted values for argc, argv and flag could be erroneous, so these values should be checked at runtime.